# Export PostgreSQL functions

Tags: postgresql, function, pg-dump

I am having a trouble exporting PostgreSQL functions using `pg_dump`.
It appears I can only export functions written in PL/pgSQL, not in C.
I am using

```bash
pg_dump v -Fc -h hostname -U user -d database_name > database.dmp
```

Still when I do

```bash
pg_restore -l database.dmp > content.list
```

The functions under the `public` schema of that database are not there. Any suggestions?

I tried to export all objects under one database, but some functions are missing.

Answer (score 0):

C functions are dumped just like any other functions. My guess is that these functions are not dumped because they are part of an extension. Restoring the dump will execute `CREATE EXTENSION`, which will restore the functions.